# Unable to see the route line from my location to the clicked place

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mapbox

I am using mapbox map for displaying a map in my react native screen however, after checking the coords hardcoded and dynamically I am unable to see the route line, please have a look at the code below:

```
const initialLng = 30.3451;
const initialLat = 10.3753; 

MapboxGL.setWellKnownTileServer('Mapbox');
MapboxGL.setAccessToken('<TOKEN>');

const Opt = () => {
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState([initialLng, initialLat]);
  const [routeGeoJSON, setRouteGeoJSON] = useState(null);
   const [routeFeatureCollection, setRouteFeatureCollection] = useState(null);
```

this is used for allowing permissions

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Request location permissions when the component mounts
    requestLocationPermissions();
  }, []);

  const requestLocationPermissions = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const response = await Permissions.requestMultiple(['android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION', 'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION']);
      const granted = response['android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'] === 'granted' &&
                      response['android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'] === 'granted';
      if (!granted) {
        console.warn('Location permissions not granted.');
      }
    }
  };

  const handleMapPress = (event) => {
    setSelectedLocation(event.geometry.coordinates);
    fetchAndDisplayRoute();
  };

  const fetchAndDisplayRoute = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/${initialLng},${initialLat};${selectedLocation[0]},${selectedLocation[1]}?access_token=<TOKEN>`
      );
      const routeData = await response.json();
      console.log('Route Data:', routeData);
      const routeCoordinates = polyline.decode(routeData.routes[0].geometry);

      // Transform the decoded coordinates to an array of [longitude, latitude]
      const routeGeometry = routeCoordinates.map(coord => [coord[1], coord[0]]);
      // Make sure the coordinates are in the correct format
      const routeFeature = {
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {},
        geometry: {
          type: 'LineString',
          coordinates: routeCoordinates,
        },
      };

     const newRouteFeatureCollection = {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: [routeFeature], 
      };

      setRouteFeatureCollection(newRouteFeatureCollection);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching and displaying route:', error);
    }
  };
```

here is my View component

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapboxGL.MapView
      zoomEnabled={true}
      styleURL='mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
       style={styles.map}
        onPress={handleMapPress}>
        <MapboxGL.Camera
          zoomLevel={15}
          centerCoordinate={selectedLocation} 
          pitch={60}
          animationMode='flyTo'
          animationDuration={6000}
        />
        <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
          id="marker"
          coordinate={selectedLocation} 
        />
      
          <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id="routeSource" shape={routeFeatureCollection}>
            <MapboxGL.LineLayer id="routeLayer" style={styles.route} />
          </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
        
        <MapboxGL.UserLocation />
      </MapboxGL.MapView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I am relatively new to react native and the tech area so Any help will be much appreciated

my logs show this output: [logoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmEyo.png)
that means my routeFeatureCollection is getting populated with data then why can not it display the routing line? I'm stuck here please help